# Regx pattern with both matching and non matching pattern

Tags: preg-replace

I have written regex to validate URL which could be either matching all conditions 1, 2 and 3 like

src="//www.googletagmanager.com/pq.html?id=FDGDF-ASDCF"     Condition1(Matching)
src="/Folder1/Images/RTimequest_banne345435.png"        Condition1(Matching)

src="http://img.jp.mysite.com/imgv4/common/arrows/arrow-double-r01.gif"     Condition2(Not Matching)
src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-MQNC2Z4"     Condition3(Not Matching)

The regex that I have used is:

src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""]

Also tested Online [REGEX TESTER](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Bn-z%5D&i=just%20the%20second%20half%20of%20the%20alphabet)

But I want to skip Not Matching Condition 2 and 3(URL starts with www or HTTP) in the same regex pattern.

```
string pattern = @"src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]";

string replacement = "src=" + '"' + "www.mysite.com" + "$1" + '"' + " ";

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);

string WebResp_html = rgx.Replace(WebResp_html, replacement);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a negative lookahead.

(?!.*http|.*www)

So it becomes

(?!.*http|.*www)src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""]

This checks to see if the string contains http or www, if so then its no match.